# Read CSV and Call a Thirdparty API Performance Issue

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I have a system where multiple user can login and upload csv. I have to read the csv file and call a thirparty api (FEDEX) to calculate shipping cost. Right now I read the csv to db and iterate to perform the shipping calculation, which takes a lot of time (as the csv can be of any size). What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see where the performance is bad? (I.e. network latency, database performance, …) It sounds like there are many moving parts to this, so without further information this can't be answered.

Comment: The issue is that the server hangs during the execution

Comment: The server hangs? Then you've either got a faulty server or there is so much contention on disk I/O that the terminal seems stuck. Checking the use of "swap" comes to mind here. If it is disk I/O, then that is most likely your bottleneck. If a lot of swap is used and pages are constantly swapped in and out, you have to get more RAM or reconfigure relevant applications to use less so that it doesn't need to swap.